# How does git creates 'author' for commit?

Tags: git, bitbucket

Somehow commits linked to the wrong (always the same author) in git (we are using bitbucket).
Why it could be so?

Answer (score 2):

You need to explicitly set your author in your `~/.gitconfig`. Otherwise Git will attempt to guess based on the logged-in user and hostname.

You can use the command `git config` for this:

```
$ git config --global user.name "John Smith"
$ git config --global user.email jsmith@example.com
```

Comment: I want it to make attempt. There are a lot of commiters.

Comment: Previously it was doing just that. And I'm okay with it.

Comment: Each of your comitters should be doing this on their local machine. There's no way (within Git) to automate this. It's up to your developers to setup their local environment for development.

Answer (score 0):

It can be caused for several reasons:

- Wrong username/email in the .gitconfig file (located in the user home dir)
- When using `SSH key` if the key was copied from different account so bitbucket grab the information attached to the ssh key
- If someone override the global setting for the specific project

type `git config -l` to view the current username/email in your config file

Good luck.